# Insert named parameter of type date into HQL Insert

Tags: c#, nhibernate, hql

I am trying to execute an HQL insert statement to insert some parameters into a table that I have mapped to an entity.

Here is what I am currently working on (which throws an exception):

```
Insert Into Entity1
(ForeignKey1, ForeignKey2, Date1, Date2)

SELECT this_.ForeignKey1, 
       cast(:param1 as int) as ForeignKeyValue2, 
       cast(:param2 as DateTime) as DateValue1, 
       cast(:param3 as DateTime) as DateValue2
FROM OtherEntity this_
WHERE ...
```

If I leave out the 2 date fields the insert works, so I know that I am close.  I just need to figure out how to get nhibernate to see my dates as dates.

The exception:

```
insertion type [NHibernate.Type.Int32Type] and selection type  
[NHibernate.Dialect.Function.CastFunction+LazyType] at position 1 are not compatible
[Insert Into Entity1
(ForeignKey1, ForeignKey2, Date1, Date2)

SELECT this_.ForeignKey1, 
       cast(:param1 as int) as ForeignKeyValue2, 
       cast(:param2 as DateTime) as DateValue1, 
       cast(:param3 as DateTime) as DateValue2
FROM OtherEntity this_
WHERE ...
```

If anyone has experience with doing this sort of thing please feel free to help.  Also if you know how to use HQL cast on DateTimes that would help too.  DBMS is MS SQL 2008.:

Comment: Why the SQL cast? Why not just send the right parameter types from the NH call?

Comment: Can we see the code that sets the parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never need to cast, just set the parameters as the correct type, e.g.

```
var hql = "insert into Entity1 (fkid, mydate) 
  select fkid, :date from OtherEntity";

session.CreateQuery(hql)
  .setDateTime("date", DateTime.Now)
  .ExecuteUpdate();
```

Comment: Trying this give me a null reference exception.  Assuming that this actually works for you I will try to update my nhibernate DLL's as I am still using 2.1.2.  I'll post the results.  Thanks

Comment: Please post a) the database structure of id and a date field, 2) the actual exception (the inner one)

Comment: There is no inner exception (super helpful right...).  It's just a null reference exception that gets thrown when I call session.CreateQuery(myQueryString).  The id's are not the issue.  Like I said, if I take out the date parameters the insert works fine the way I originally had it.  The date fields on that table are nullable so I can insert without setting them (yes I am making sure to pass an actual date in when setting the parameters).  I'm still working on getting the DLL's updated.  I'll let you know if I have any success with that.

Comment: Are you sure a) the session is not NULL and b) and the null reference exception is not because other parameters/properties etc are set correctly. The HQL should be fine as is for V 2.2

Comment: Yes I'm sure.  Also I was using V2.1.  Updated the Dll for nhibernate to 3.2 and it works now using the code you suggested in your answer.  Thanks for your help!